Further customizing the pipeline at run time
Can I have an Azure pipeline parameter show up depending on the selection of another parameter?
What I mean by that is that I have an azure-pipeline.yml that will call templates which will call other templates.
When the pipeline is triggered, it asks to select one of 3 options. Something like this:

My question is, I'd like the Work item parameter to be displayed only if #2 is selected. Can that be done? All other times, it may be greyed out, or not visible too.
These are all being done using YAML files.


My question is, I'd like the Work item parameter to be displayed only if #2 is selected. Can that be done? All other times, it may be greyed out, or not visible too.

It's not supported conditional display of parameters based on the selection of another parameter. You can check similar ticket for the details.
If you would like the feature, it's recommended to raise a feature request in community link, thanks.

Ok this answers my question. Thank you.
